# Best way to access (grand grand) parent element in gui

Tags: c++, gui, singleton, qt, static-access

I'm creating a multi window gui program, in  c++ with Qt Widgets. I do have many custom gui elements, which usually are c++ classes inherited from `QWidget` or other Qt elements. When `foo` is the main window, it often looks like this:

```cpp
Foo = new Foo();
Bar1 *widget1(foo);
Bar2 *widget2(widget1);
Bar3 *widget3(widget2);
Bar4 *widget4(widget3);

foo->addWidget(widget1);
widget1->addWidget(widget2);
widget2->addWidget(widget3);
widget3->addWidget(widget4);
```

Actually I use `std::shared_ptr` everywhere but I'm omitting that here for the sake of readability. Also this is simplified, the order is not always like this and there may be other Qt elements in between.

The argument in the constructors is the "parent" Window. Qt handles the deletion of all my Widgets using the parent structures.

My problem is, that sometimes, I need to access elements of my main window `foo` from some `Bar` widget down the road. E.g.: "If this is clicked, add another tab to the `QTabwidget` in `foo`. I do not always know, how many layers there are between `foo` and `widgetX`.

What's the best way to have a reference to `foo` in the lowest layer?

1. The easiest way would be to make `foo` a singleton since I only ever have one `foo` window and once it get's closed, my program terminates anyway. But making the whole class static comes with it's own drawbacks.
2. Add a reference to `foo` to all my constructors and pass it through them. I'd have a reference to `foo` in many places where I do not need one.
3. I can access the parent reference that got passed through the constructors, but it's a pointer to `QWidget`. I'd have to cast it, check whether it's actually `Foo` and not `Bar2`, and then continue until I have found `Foo`.
4. Set `foo` as a parent for everything, even if it is not really the parent (e.g. in a new Window). This would keep all my elements in memory until `foo` is destroyed.
5. Use signals and slots. This sometimes works, but if I'm already 3 layers below `foo` when creating `widget4`, I can't connect them without `foo`.

Currently I have a mixed mess where I sometimes pass a reference to `foo`, have some static elements in `foo` and at some point cast the parent widget to `foo`.

What would be a good approach here?

Comment: Do you want to access grand parent because of the hierarchy? Or because it has some responsibilities and happen to be the grand parent by coincidence? Is it only about gui properties/behaviors or is it possible that you need grand partent access for a non gui reason?

Comment: One use case is the modification of other gui elements the main windows holts. But it also holds some data I want to modify from a lower level element. Maybe that's where my problem originates, a gui element holding non-gui data.

Comment: Please clarify your issue with slots and signals. In your example the foo and any of the widgets are in same scope so you sure can connect them directly

Comment: My example is oversimplified, e.g. widget3 would be created in widget2's constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have your own widget class that wraps the Qt widget or descends from it, you can add a GetGodfather() method who's implementation looks somewhat like this:

```
if (this.parent == NULL)
{
    return this;
}
else
{
    return this.parent.GetGodfather();
}
```

Or, if you want to be smart about it:

```
return (this.Parent == NULL) ? this : this.parent.GetGodfather();
```

Comment: I wondered if something like this would work, it should, shouldn't it? My idea was without the wrapper class but this makes this pretty straightforward I guess. Will play around with that a bit and test it, thanks!

Comment: I would caution against this. The moment your nested GUI element starts relying on the structure of the GUI "above" it, it's becomes non-reusable, and calcifies a dependency between that GUI component and the one particular context it's used in. Ideally, the parent should pass child components all the objects they need to collaborate with, in a way that prevents them from needing to "reach out" and access things themselves

Comment: @Alexander It is a common way to produce a path to a node in a tree. The only dependency is the tree structure. Yes, a tree node is meaningless outside the scope of a tree structure, this is by design so I don't see any merit in the statement that it is not reusable independent from the tree structure. Any node has a parent (or not if it is a root). That is as far as reaching out goes, it gets all it wants to know directly from its parent and remains unaware of the ultimate source of the information returned or the route taken to obtain it. That looks pretty elegant to me. [...]

Comment: @Alexander [...] More so than telling each note at creation time what the root or its path is, momentary properties that may change in the course of its life cycle. That would hardly be ideal.

Comment: If it only queries for the immediate parent, and not siblings, cousins or ancestors, that can be OK. But going up more than 1 level (which is what I though `GetGodfather()` was doing, but now I'm not sure) is a really mad idea, IMO. Instead, I would pass the child a reference to a collaborator object which is stable over the lifetime of the GUI (regardless of the movement of elements within the GUI), which can be a stable source for data. Perhaps the parent can be that collaborator, but I still rather inject that then have the child access it directly

Comment: @Alexander: it is not a "mad idea", quite the opposite, we have used this technique to find the "uppermost window" of an application for years in several desktop applications, and the potential drawbacks were acceptable. It was actually Winforms/C#, but relying on the tree structure of a form and its controls or widgets will work in most GUI frameworks I know and not induce any unacceptable constraints to reusability.

Comment: Finding the window makes sense, it’s singular and guaranteed to be present for most application GUIs

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same problem and solved it via a static member function of `Foo` that traverses parents of a child widget until one of type `Foo` is found:

```cpp
class Foo : public QWidget {

public:
    // static member function to find Foo parent
    static Foo* findFrom(QWidget* widget) {
        while (widget) {
            Foo* foo = qobject_cast<Foo*>(widget);
            if (foo) {
                return foo; // found a Foo parent
            }
            widget = widget->parentWidget();
        }
        return nullptr; // no Foo parent found
    }
};
```

In some child widget's member method, you can then call `Foo* parentFoo = Foo::findFrom(this)` to get the `Foo`-pointer.

Comment: I've been out of c++ for a while, does this work if `widget` is another custom class that inherits from QWidget too? I like toe idea to search for a specific type of widget though.

Comment: Yes, this works flawlessly, since the `CustomWidget*` to a derived class that you pass to this method is implicitly cast to a `QWidget*`.